# Backup or file syncronization between local network PC's

Tags: project-organization, file-organization

We're working on a site who's document management policy is to put all files onto the network (i.e. My Documents mapped to a network server) for all personal or project related documents, or files.

The problem is that the network has poor uptime. We have configuration files for tools, project related code libraries, and other development related products on the network and the poor uptime creates issues with productivity and timelines.

I'm  thinking about using everyone's PC to do a file synchronization or peer to peer backups to provide the availability and redundancy that we need.

I'm leaning more towards file sync as there is no requirement for security, and the intent is to share the information.

Has anyone tried this approach?  If so what products were used and what were the pros's and con's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like peer to peer backup solutions like CrashPlan will do the job.